# `ST_3DArea` almost unusable on Google Cloud SQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, postgis

I am having a hard time configuring my Cloud SQL database. I have almost migrated all my geospatial data into the database, and now I am trying to run my queries. Those queries are hard to swallow, because I am getting the following error in *TablePlus*.

```
SYSCALL error: EOF detected
```

The SQL logs of Google Cloud show me that this is a "Segmentation fault":

```
server process (PID 100639) was terminated by signal 11: Segmentation fault
```

---

The strange part is, that this is only happening for **some** geometries. For example `POINT(0 0)` is not throwing, and simply giving me `0`. However, something like `SRID=4326;POLYGON((6.677307335576974 51.41657286222727 30.061,6.677292566733933 51.41659692380416 30.061,6.677292566733933 51.41659692380416 27.701,6.677307335576974 51.41657286222727 27.701,6.677307335576974 51.41657286222727 30.061))` is giving me an error.

Comment: Is there a simple example that reproduces the problem?  If so, please show it to us.

Comment: The error message "SYSCALL error: EOF detected" indicates that the ST_3DArea function is trying to read beyond the end of the geometry data. This can happen if the geometry data is corrupted or invalid.

Comment: Just a short update, I after contacting the Google Support: "I would like to inform you that this is a known issue in our end where there is some issue in the postgis dependency CGAL. Our product team is actively working on this."